# Oracle SQL UNION with SELECT AS subqueries

Tags: sql, oracle, select, union

I'm stuck trying to create a view from a SELECT statement that should take some fields from a table. The problem is I need to use the same field at least twice, depending on its foo and bar. I'm trying to do something like

```
SELECT x, y FROM 
( 
(SELECT foo from table where abc='TYPE 1') as x
UNION
(SELECT foo from table where def='TYPE 2') as y
) table;
```

The statement fails because I can't seem to be able to use 'as x' and 'as y' in a UNION statement. Is there any way to bypass that?

**L.E.:**
What I need is something on the lines of:

```
SELECT x, y FROM 
(
(SELECT foo from table where abc='TYPE 1') as x,
(SELECT foo from table where def='TYPE 2') as y
) table
```

Where x and y are foo which is a number.
Base table is:

```
FOO |  ABC   |  DEF
_________________________
100 | TYPE 1 | ----
300 | ------ | TYPE 2
```

Expected output is:

```
 X  |  Y  |  ABC   |  DEF
_________________________
100 | --- | TYPE 1 | ----
--- | 300 | ------ | TYPE 2
```

I need to divide foo into subcolumns of itself based on abc and def, which are columns in the same table.

Comment: Provide sample data and expected result. Your use of UNION is entirely incorrect, given the outer part of the query.

Comment: @JohnHC my expected result is to have the foo column split into two different columns based on it's status and type. Say I have a few lines with different sums. Sum $100 has type Debit and status Unpaid. Sum $200 has type Credit and status Paid. I need to separate them based on that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

since you are expecting this from same table.

**try this below by changing case accordingly as required

```
select distinct c.*
from (select foo, null, abc, null
      from table a
      where abc = 'type 1'
      union all
      select null, abc, null, def
      from table b
      where def = 'type 2'
     ) c ;
```

Comment: I get column ambiguously defined from c.* when i replace it with my table.*

Comment: ok., you can use as below

select distinct c.* from 
 (
select foo x,null y,abc,null def from table a where abc='type 1'
union all
select null,abc,null,def from table b where abc='type 2'
 ) c ;

the exception was i have mentioned null twice in table 1, hence aliased them

Answer (score 2):

The columns available for select when querying a subquery are limited to the columns which that subquery itself selects.  So the following is what I would write here:

```
SELECT foo FROM yourTable WHERE abc = 'TYPE 1'
UNION ALL
SELECT foo FROM yourTable WHERE def = 'TYPE 2';
```

I use `UNION ALL`, because if you really want to use `UNION` and remove duplicates, then the following single query would be the same as your original attempt:

```
SELECT DISTINCT foo
FROM yourTable
WHERE abc = 'TYPE 1' OR def = 'TYPE 2';
```

**Edit:**

Maybe you want this:

```
SELECT foo, 'TYPE 1' AS type FROM yourTable WHERE abc = 'TYPE 1'
UNION ALL
SELECT foo, 'TYPE 2' FROM yourTable WHERE def = 'TYPE 2'
ORDER BY type, foo;
```

Comment: Ok but if I do this the result will be just a column with abc values in it. I need to know how to separate them.

Comment: @OctavianCatusanu I'm sort of guessing what you want, because your question is not clear.  Try the query at the bottom of my answer.

Comment: Based on your comment I arrived at this:                                            
`SELECT foo as x FROM myTable where abc = 'TYPE 1'
UNION ALL
SELECT foo as y FROM myTable where def = 'TYPE 2'
ORDER by foo`                   but it only shows x in the results, not x and y

Comment: What you are asking for makes no sense, because there is no information present which _relates_ an `x` value to a `y` value.  Edit your question and show the expected output.

Comment: Edited my answer

Answer (score 2):

you can use this technique that creates 2 temporary tables and you then join them

```
WITH 
     X AS (SELECT FOO FROM TABLE WHERE  ABC = 'TYPE 1'),
     Y AS (SELECT FOO FROM TABLE WHERE  DEF = 'TYPE 2')

SELECT * FROM X
UNION
SELECT * FROM Y
```

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to get `columns` but not `rows`, so using `UNION` is not the case. You may try the following( assuming you have a primary key column called `id` ) :

```
create table "table" ( id int, foo varchar(10), abc varchar(100), def varchar(100));
insert into "table" values(1, 'abc', 'TYPE 1', 'TYPE 2');
insert into "table" values(2, 'def', 'TYPE 3', 'TYPE 2');

SELECT  
    (SELECT foo from "table" where abc='TYPE 1' and id = t2.id ) as x,
    (SELECT foo from "table" where def='TYPE 2' and id = t2.id ) as y
 FROM "table" t2;

 X    Y
---  ---
abc  abc
def
```